# Changing yeoman generated Gruntfile.js file to separate .css files from .scss files

Tags: sass, compass-sass, gruntjs, yeoman, livereload

I'm trying to amend slightly the default webapp Gruntfile.js generated by Yeoman (1.0). The default sets both .css and .scss files under 'styles', but does not pickup subdirectory .scss partials under a subdirectory, which means that they are not rendered into .css.

I've been trying to amend this so that my .scss files live under '/styles/scss/' and my generated .css files live under '/styles/css/' directory.

I've managed to get .scss files in subdirectories to render into .css but now livereload does not update when a partial is changed, although I can see the 'watch' task rendering my .scss into .css when a change is made.

Any thoughts or ideas on how to get livereload to automatically render the .css when a .scss file is changed?

Any help appreciated!

Current amended Grunt.js file:

```
// Generated on 2013-06-21 using generator-webapp 0.2.4
'use strict';
var LIVERELOAD_PORT = 35729;
var lrSnippet = require('connect-livereload')({port: LIVERELOAD_PORT});
var mountFolder = function (connect, dir) {
    return connect.static(require('path').resolve(dir));
};

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    // load all grunt tasks
    require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

    // configurable paths
    var yeomanConfig = {
        app: 'app',
        dist: 'dist'
    };

    grunt.initConfig({
        yeoman: yeomanConfig,
        watch: {
            options: {
                nospawn: true
            },
            coffee: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.coffee'],
                tasks: ['coffee:dist']
            },
            coffeeTest: {
                files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.coffee'],
                tasks: ['coffee:test']
            },
            compass: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/**/*.{scss,sass}'],
                tasks: ['compass:server']
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    livereload: LIVERELOAD_PORT
                },
                files: [
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/*.html',
                    '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/styles/css/*.css',
                    '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
                ]
            }
        },
        connect: {
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                // change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
                hostname: 'localhost'
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    middleware: function (connect) {
                        return [
                            lrSnippet,
                            mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                            mountFolder(connect, yeomanConfig.app)
                        ];
                    }
                }
            },
            test: {
                options: {
                    middleware: function (connect) {
                        return [
                            mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                            mountFolder(connect, 'test')
                        ];
                    }
                }
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    middleware: function (connect) {
                        return [
                            mountFolder(connect, yeomanConfig.dist)
                        ];
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        open: {
            server: {
                path: 'http://localhost:<%= connect.options.port %>'
            }
        },
        clean: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    dot: true,
                    src: [
                        '.tmp',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
                        '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
                    ]
                }]
            },
            server: '.tmp'
        },
        jshint: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
            },
            all: [
                'Gruntfile.js',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                '!<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/vendor/*',
                'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
            ]
        },
        mocha: {
            all: {
                options: {
                    run: true,
                    urls: ['http://localhost:<%= connect.options.port %>/index.html']
                }
            }
        },
        coffee: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
                    src: '{,*/}*.coffee',
                    dest: '.tmp/scripts',
                    ext: '.js'
                }]
            },
            test: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'test/spec',
                    src: '{,*/}*.coffee',
                    dest: '.tmp/spec',
                    ext: '.js'
                }]
            }
        },
        compass: {
            options: { 
                sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/scss',
                cssDir: '.tmp/styles/css',
                generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
                imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
                fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
                importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components',
                httpImagesPath: '/images',
                httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
                httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
                relativeAssets: false
            },
            dist: {},
            server: {
                options: {
                    debugInfo: true
                }
            }
        },
        // not used since Uglify task does concat,
        // but still available if needed
        /*concat: {
            dist: {}
        },*/
        // not enabled since usemin task does concat and uglify
        // check index.html to edit your build targets
        // enable this task if you prefer defining your build targets here
        /*uglify: {
            dist: {}
        },*/
        rev: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    src: [
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/css/*.css',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp}',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        useminPrepare: {
            options: {
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
            },
            html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'
        },
        usemin: {
            options: {
                dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
            },
            html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
            css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/css/*.css']
        },
        imagemin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
                }]
            }
        },
        svgmin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
                }]
            }
        },
        cssmin: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/css/main.css': [
                        '.tmp/styles/css/*.css',
                        '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/css/*.css'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        htmlmin: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    /*removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                    // https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/44
                    //collapseWhitespace: true,
                    collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                    removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                    removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                    useShortDoctype: true,
                    removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                    removeOptionalTags: true*/
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                    src: '*.html',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
                }]
            }
        },
        // Put files not handled in other tasks here
        copy: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                    src: [
                        '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                        '.htaccess',
                        'images/{,*/}*.{webp,gif}',
                        'styles/fonts/*'
                    ]
                }, {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/images',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
                    src: [
                        'generated/*'
                    ]
                }]
            }
        },
        concurrent: {
            server: [
                'compass',
                'coffee:dist'
            ],
            test: [
                'coffee'
            ],
            dist: [
                'coffee',
                'compass',
                'imagemin',
                'svgmin',
                'htmlmin'
            ]
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
        if (target === 'dist') {
            return grunt.task.run(['build', 'open', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'concurrent:server',
            'connect:livereload',
            'open',
            'watch'
        ]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('test', [
        'clean:server',
        'concurrent:test',
        'connect:test',
        'mocha'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean:dist',
        'useminPrepare',
        'concurrent:dist',
        'cssmin',
        'concat',
        'uglify',
        'copy:dist',
        'rev',
        'usemin'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'jshint',
        'test',
        'build'
    ]);
};
```

Comment: See this question: [Yeoman: Triggering LiveReload on change of SCSS files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16950612/yeoman-triggering-livereload-on-change-of-scss-files). The [chosen answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16975967/483260) (change `nospawn` to `false`) worked for me, with that same generator, after making pretty much the same changes to my own Gruntfile (as well as when I tested by trying it out with a fresh buildout using that generator).

Comment: @natchiketa, you should report that as an answer.

Comment: Excellent - fixed the issue for me as well. Thanks Natchiketa!

Comment: @lolmaus I didn't do that because if that's the answer to this question, then that means that this is a duplicate question to the question I referenced. I think if anyone finds the `nospawn` thing to be helpful, they should just go over to that question and upvote the answer by @Stephen